# How do I query a generic relation queryset in Django to annotate a list with objects whos generic relations is the object?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Model with a Generic relations.
I want MyModel.objects.filter() and do something to add a list containing the objects where their Generic relations is its row from MyModel.objects.filter()

I want to try to make it in one query if it can be done. I am using MySQL if that effects anything.

To clarify I want to

```
    list_of_my_models = MyModel.objects.filter()
```

then do something so that i can

```
    for my_model in list_of_my_models:
        for related_my_model in my_model.related_my_models:
             // do something with related_my_model
```

I tried using OuterRef in annotate with a Subquery, but get the error.
"Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field." When i visit the page that uses it.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    x1= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    x2= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    x3= models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

def custom_models(object):
    my_models= MyModel.objects.filter(object_id=OuterRef('pk'),  content_type=ContentType.objects.get(model='mymodel', app_label='app_my_model'))
    return MyModel.objects.filter(
        object_id=object.pk,
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(object)
    ).annotate(related_my_models=Subquery(my_models))
```

So is there any way to fix this or is there an other way to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Try this:
`MyModel.objects.filter(object_id=OuterRef('pk'), content_type__model='mymodel', content_type__app_label='app_my_model'))`

If you are not sure about the case, then:
`MyModel.objects.filter(object_id=OuterRef('pk'), content_type__model__icontains='mymodel', content_type__app_label__icontains='app_my_model'))`

Comment: Tried and made nothing seems to change.